# Python Selenium Project - create a table from a list

Tags: python, list, selenium

I'm new to Python, as a part of of Selenium web scraping project, I managed to pull the data I need and turned it into a list as below;

```
clean_data = ['06/25/21 (w)', '1', '105', '382', '0.27', '11,396', '8,654', '1.32', '40.56%', '07/02/21 (w)', '8', '43', '80', '0.54', '6,480', '6,288', '1.03', '32.19%', '07/09/21 (w)', '15', '30', '251', '0.12', '1,062', '458', '2.32', '30.51%', '07/16/21 (m)', '22', '198', '235', '0.84', '87,464', '74,588', '1.17', '31.20%', '07/23/21 (w)', '29', '16', '28', '0.57', '1,043', '1,387', '0.75', '32.20%', '07/30/21 (w)', '36', '33', '15', '2.20', '686', '482', '1.42', '32.21%', '08/20/21 (m)', '57', '111', '171', '0.65', '1,211', '951', '1.27', '32.86%', '10/15/21 (m)', '113', '5', '41', '0.12', '16,005', '10,111', '1.58', '34.58%', '12/17/21 (m)', '176', '76', '258', '0.29', '35,904', '59,572', '0.60', '35.43%', '01/21/22 (m)', '211', '6', '72', '0.08', '2,124', '6,998', '0.30', '34.90%', '01/20/23 (m)', '575', '15', '19', '0.79', '2,697', '2,217', '1.22', '34.75%']
```

The original table has 9 columns and can have n rows depending on source data.

I would like to turn this list into a 9 columns X n rows table, the table should look something like this

> 06/25/21 (w) ___  1 ___ 105 ___ 382 ___ 0.27 ___ 11,396 ___ 8,654 ___ 1.32 ___ 40.56% 
> 07/02/21 (w) ___  8 ___ 43 ___ 80 ___ 0.54 ___ 6,480 ___ 6,288 ___ 1.03 ___ 32.19% 
> 07/16/21 (m) ___  22 ___ 198 ___ 235 ___ 0.84 ___ 87,464 ___ 74,588 ___ 1.17 ___ 31.20% 
> 07/23/21 (w) ___  29 ___ 16 ___ 28 ___ 0.57 ___ 1,043 ___ 1,387 ___ 0.75 ___ 32.20% 
> 07/30/21 (w) ___  36 ___ 33 ___ 15 ___ 2.20 ___ 686 ___ 482 ___ 1.42 ___ 32.21% 
> 08/20/21 (m) ___  57 ___ 111 ___ 171 ___ 0.65 ___ 1,211 ___ 951 ___ 1.27 ___ 32.86% 
> 10/15/21 (m) ___  113 ___ 5 ___ 41 ___ 0.12 ___ 16,005 ___ 10,111 ___ 1.58 ___ 34.58% 
> 12/17/21 (m) ___  176 ___ 76 ___ 258 ___ 0.29 ___ 35,904 ___ 59,572 ___ 0.60 ___ 35.43% 
> 01/21/22 (m) ___  211 ___ 6 ___ 72 ___ 0.08 ___ 2,124 ___ 6,998 ___ 0.30 ___ 34.90% 
> 01/20/23 (m) ___  575 ___ 15 ___ 19 ___ 0.79 ___ 2,697 ___ 2,217 ___ 1.22 ___ 34.75%

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,
MT

Comment: Do you need to use selenium to scrape the table from the website or can you use pandas: [pd.read_html(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just format the `clean_data` list to text table, you can do:

```py
N = 9
max_len = max(len(w) for w in clean_data)
f = "{:<" + str(max_len + 2) + "}"

for i in range(0, len(clean_data), N):
    print((f * N).format(*clean_data[i : i + N]))
```

Prints:

```
06/25/21 (w)  1             105           382           0.27          11,396        8,654         1.32          40.56%        
07/02/21 (w)  8             43            80            0.54          6,480         6,288         1.03          32.19%        
07/09/21 (w)  15            30            251           0.12          1,062         458           2.32          30.51%        
07/16/21 (m)  22            198           235           0.84          87,464        74,588        1.17          31.20%        
07/23/21 (w)  29            16            28            0.57          1,043         1,387         0.75          32.20%        
07/30/21 (w)  36            33            15            2.20          686           482           1.42          32.21%        
08/20/21 (m)  57            111           171           0.65          1,211         951           1.27          32.86%        
10/15/21 (m)  113           5             41            0.12          16,005        10,111        1.58          34.58%        
12/17/21 (m)  176           76            258           0.29          35,904        59,572        0.60          35.43%        
01/21/22 (m)  211           6             72            0.08          2,124         6,998         0.30          34.90%        
01/20/23 (m)  575           15            19            0.79          2,697         2,217         1.22          34.75%
```

---

EDIT: To create a dataframe from `clean_data`:

```py
N = 9
tmp = []
for i in range(0, len(clean_data), N):
    tmp.append(clean_data[i : i + N])

df = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               0    1    2    3     4       5       6     7       8
0   06/25/21 (w)    1  105  382  0.27  11,396   8,654  1.32  40.56%
1   07/02/21 (w)    8   43   80  0.54   6,480   6,288  1.03  32.19%
2   07/09/21 (w)   15   30  251  0.12   1,062     458  2.32  30.51%
3   07/16/21 (m)   22  198  235  0.84  87,464  74,588  1.17  31.20%
4   07/23/21 (w)   29   16   28  0.57   1,043   1,387  0.75  32.20%
5   07/30/21 (w)   36   33   15  2.20     686     482  1.42  32.21%
6   08/20/21 (m)   57  111  171  0.65   1,211     951  1.27  32.86%
7   10/15/21 (m)  113    5   41  0.12  16,005  10,111  1.58  34.58%
8   12/17/21 (m)  176   76  258  0.29  35,904  59,572  0.60  35.43%
9   01/21/22 (m)  211    6   72  0.08   2,124   6,998  0.30  34.90%
10  01/20/23 (m)  575   15   19  0.79   2,697   2,217  1.22  34.75%
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, I tried to turn this into a data frame but seems like each row is one cell, how can I turn each row to 9 separate cells?